# Unity Project in Android Studio 3.0 Build Error : com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/games/bridge/BuildConfig;

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, apk, build.gradle, google-play-games

I imported the unity project I am working on to Android Studio so as to get rid of READ_PHONE_STATE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions unity 2017.2 automatically annoyingly add to APK build.

I successfully managed to import the project to Android Studio 3.0 after changing build.gradle version from 2.1.0 to 3.0.0. clean the project and now I am ready to build.

the problem is that I can't build. I am getting there errors :

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/games/bridge/BuildConfig;
```

and

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/games/bridge/BuildConfig;
```

and

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/tappx/sdk/android/BuildConfig;
```

and

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/tappx/sdk/android/BuildConfig;
```

My unity project has the following plugins added :

- PlayGames for unity v 0.9.42
- Firebase SDK (analytics, dynamiclinks, notifications, remoteConfig) v 4.2.1
- IronSource SDK
- TappX SDK

please have a look over my build.gradle file

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'Admob_appbrain-sdk-13.22', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'common', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-analytics-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-analytics-impl-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-config-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-dynamic-links-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-messaging-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'GoogleAIDL', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'GooglePlay', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-appinvite-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-auth-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-auth-base-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-base-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-basement-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-drive-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-games-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-nearby-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-tasks-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-compat-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-core-ui-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-core-utils-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-fragment-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-media-compat-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-v4-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile project(':Firebase')
    compile project(':firebase-analytics-impl-license-11.4.2')
    compile project(':firebase-analytics-license-11.4.2')
    compile project(':firebase-analytics-unity-4.2.1')
    compile project(':firebase-app-unity-4.2.1')
    compile project(':firebase-common-11.4.2')
    compile project(':firebase-common-license-11.4.2')
    compile project(':firebase-config-license-11.4.2')
    compile project(':firebase-config-unity-4.2.1')
    compile project(':firebase-core-11.4.2')
    compile project(':firebase-dynamic-links-license-11.4.2')
    compile project(':firebase-dynamic-links-unity-4.2.1')
    compile project(':firebase-iid-11.4.2')
    compile project(':firebase-iid-license-11.4.2')
    compile project(':firebase-messaging-license-11.4.2')
    compile project(':firebase-messaging-unity-4.2.1')
    compile project(':GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin')
    compile project(':gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.42')
    compile project(':IronSource')
    compile project(':play-services-appinvite-license-11.4.2')
    compile project(':play-services-base-license-11.4.2')
    compile project(':play-services-basement-license-11.4.2')
    compile project(':play-services-tasks-license-11.4.2')
    compile project(':TappxSDK')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 25
        applicationId 'play.TheEgg'
    }

    lintOptions {


abortOnError false
}

aaptOptions {
    noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'
}

signingConfigs { release {
    storeFile file('C:/Keystores/user.keystore')
    storePassword 'STORE_PASS'
    keyAlias 'KEY_ALIAS'
    keyPassword 'KEY_PASS'
} }

buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
        jniDebuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

}

I tried to add multiDexEnabled = true - but it didn't make any difference to the output.

here is last part of Grade Console Log :

```
:firebase-core-11.4.2:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-core-11.4.2:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-core-11.4.2:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-core-11.4.2:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-dynamic-links-license-11.4.2:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-dynamic-links-license-11.4.2:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-dynamic-links-license-11.4.2:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-dynamic-links-license-11.4.2:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-dynamic-links-unity-4.2.1:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-dynamic-links-unity-4.2.1:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-dynamic-links-unity-4.2.1:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-dynamic-links-unity-4.2.1:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-iid-11.4.2:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-iid-11.4.2:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-iid-11.4.2:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-iid-11.4.2:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-iid-license-11.4.2:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-iid-license-11.4.2:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-iid-license-11.4.2:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-iid-license-11.4.2:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-messaging-license-11.4.2:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-messaging-license-11.4.2:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-messaging-license-11.4.2:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-messaging-license-11.4.2:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-messaging-unity-4.2.1:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-messaging-unity-4.2.1:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-messaging-unity-4.2.1:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:firebase-messaging-unity-4.2.1:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.42:mergeDebugShaders
:gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.42:compileDebugShaders
:gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.42:generateDebugAssets
:gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.42:mergeDebugAssets
:play-services-appinvite-license-11.4.2:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:play-services-appinvite-license-11.4.2:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:play-services-appinvite-license-11.4.2:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:play-services-appinvite-license-11.4.2:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:play-services-base-license-11.4.2:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:play-services-base-license-11.4.2:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:play-services-base-license-11.4.2:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:play-services-base-license-11.4.2:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:play-services-basement-license-11.4.2:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:play-services-basement-license-11.4.2:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:play-services-basement-license-11.4.2:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:play-services-basement-license-11.4.2:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:play-services-tasks-license-11.4.2:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:play-services-tasks-license-11.4.2:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:play-services-tasks-license-11.4.2:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:play-services-tasks-license-11.4.2:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets
:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug
:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/games/bridge/BuildConfig;","sources":[{}],"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:\ncom.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/games/bridge/BuildConfig;\n","tool":"Dex"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/games/bridge/BuildConfig;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)","sources":[{}]}

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/games/bridge/BuildConfig;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s

404 actionable tasks: 12 executed, 392 up-to-date
```

I hope I can find an answer as my work is now on hold because of this.
Thank You
Rami Ibrahim

Answer (score 0):

(I'm a developer from the Firebase C++ / Unity team)

Sounds like you hit the Dex limit. There is an experimental way using "Gradle Prebuild" in the Assets->Google Play Services->Android Settings->Settings menu option.

However, that's still experimental. If it doesn't work the current suggested workflow is to set the build system to gradle, choose "export", to export your project to gradle, enable proguard stripping in the gradle build produced, and build your project from there.

Comment: Thank you very much. tried "Gradle Prebuild" and build succeeded.